# export overloaded operator of a class

Tags: c++, export, overloading, operator-keyword

I've created (in Qt and Mingwin the specified case), a class that has the following structure:

```
#ifndef POINT2D_H
#define POINT2D_H

#include "Calculus_global.h"
#include <QtCore>

namespace Calculus
{

/** Class for definition of a point in 2D space */
class CALCULUSSHARED_EXPORT CartesianPoint2D
{
public:

    //! Constructor
    CartesianPoint2D();


    //! Set x value
    void setX(const qreal &qrX);

   // ETC ETC ETC
};

} // namespace Calculus

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// RELATED NON-MEMBER OPERATORS                                              //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//! Addition operator
Calculus::CartesianPoint2D operator +(const Calculus::CartesianPoint2D &xAPoint, const Calculus::CartesianPoint2D &xBPoint);

//! Subtraction operator
Calculus::CartesianPoint2D operator -(const Calculus::CartesianPoint2D &xAPoint, const Calculus::CartesianPoint2D &xBPoint);

// And so on...

#endif // POINT2D_H
```

When I use this library, class methods works well. But when I want to use an operator, I got the undefined reference error, for example:

```
path\sources\testcalculus.cpp:273: error: undefined reference to `operator+(Calculus::CartesianPoint2D const&, Calculus::CartesianPoint2D const&)'
```

What I must do to export also the overloaded operators and use them?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I've found... I had to write something like this in operator declaration:

    Calculus::CartesianPoint2D CALCULUSSHARED_EXPORT operator +(const Calculus::CartesianPoint2D &xAPoint, const Calculus::CartesianPoint2D &xBPoint);

Comment: Unrelated note: Your operators should be defined *inside* the `Calculus` namespace (that is, in the namespace that the type is defined). Argument Dependent Lookup will try and find the operators in the namespace of the arguments, so there is no need to make them global in the root namespace. By moving them to the same namespace you make the operators part of the interface, and you will avoid namespace pollution, and have less chances of lookup finding the wrong overload/failing due to ambiguities. Google for *interface principle*.

Comment: Ok I'll put them inside. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use CALCULUSSHARED_EXPORT in your free functions (the operators in this case) too. This (I think) is true only to Windows.